# Request, POST Axios in react native on nodejs localhost

Tags: node.js, axios

How are you ?
I have Probleme with my Axios request POST !
i have always network error

My backend is developpin with nodeJs on my localhost and use  cors

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-    Type, Authorization');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
        next();
      });
```

```
     let url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/register'
            console.log(email)
            let data = {
                email:email
            }
            Axios.post(url,data,{
                             headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                                      }

                           /* email:email,
                            password:password,
                            name:name,
                            surname:surname,*/
                       

                        }).then(function(response){
                console.log(""+response)
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err.message)
            })
```

please help me and sorry for my inglish